# JQuery - Unwrap only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got such situation:

```
<div>
    <span id="x1"></span>
    <span id="x2"></span>
    <span id="x3"></span>
</div>
```

And I am trying to get something like this:

```
<div>
    <span id="x1"></span>
</div>
<span id="x2"></span>
<div>
    <span id="x3"></span>
</div>
```

I have tried to do that using `unwrap()` function like this:

```
$('#x2').unwrap();
```

But this function removes whole `<div>`. So how can I do that using jQuery/JavaScript? Thanks for help.

Comment: do you need to preserve all the event listeners bound to original `<div>` and re-bind them also to second div?

Comment: no. it is not necessary

Comment: You put a bounty on the question, yet, from what I see, the answer solves your issue. Care to explain why it doesn't fit your needs so we can better help you?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon of course. What if I would have more than three elements and I don't know index of element which I want to remove. I am talking about that because I need it in my text editor in lists. When I select lines (in contenteditable div) in list and click a button selected elements are given classes and it is these elements that they want to unwrap.

Comment: Do you mean something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/8y7upszb/  If you could provide your actual example, it would be easier to understand and make your question better.

Comment: This is in fact **wrapping** the children of an element with a specific  **omission** of which you didn't give a rule or a principle to choice (what sub element to omit ) - reformulate and make a better specification of a requirement on your question.

Comment: Hi, I think I solved your question, and you accepted my answer. Do you need something more? If not, I think you should award me the bounty. Thanks

Comment: @TiagoCoelho Of course I will give you a bounty, but to that, I have to wait a few hours. Such a system came up with stackoverflow. But it's good that you ask, because I have one question: Will your code work if the target is more than one element?

Comment: @KacperG. the current code will not work for more than one element as a target. It is easy enough to extend it if the elements are contiguous between them. Is that what you need? I can update the answer with that bit

Comment: @TiagoCoelho if you update the answer I will be grateful PS. To give you a bounty I have to wait 4 hours more

Comment: @KacperG. OK, I updated my answer to handle some more use cases.

Comment: @TiagoCoelho Thank you very much. I will give you a bounty as soon as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the all siblings after the target element, wrap them in a new div and put them after the original container.

put the target element between both divs.

**This will work for any number of items in the container and will only unwrap the target element.**

```js
const el=$("#x2")
const parent =el.parent()
const nextSiblings=el.nextAll()
const newWrap=$("<div>").append(nextSiblings)
parent.after(newWrap)
parent.after(el)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
div{border:solid 1px red;}
span{display:block}
</style>

<div>
    <span id="x1">1</span>
    <span id="x2">2</span>
    <span id="x3">3</span>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
add possibility of unwraping more than one element and also handle removal from first or last positions.

```js
const unWrapOne=el=>{
  const parent =el.parent()
  const nextSiblings=el.last().nextAll()
  
  if(nextSiblings.length>0){
    const newWrap=$("<div>").append(nextSiblings)
    parent.after(newWrap)
  }
  
  parent.after(el)
  
  if(parent.children().length===0)
    parent.remove()
}

const unwrapSome = elements => elements.each((index,el)=>unWrapOne($(el)))

unwrapSome($("#x3,#x5")) //unwrap 2 non contiguous elements
//unwrapSome($("#x2,#x3")) //unwrap 2 contiguous elements
//unwrapSome($("#x2")) //unwrap 1 element from middle
//unwrapSome($("#x1")) //unwrap 1 element from begining
//unwrapSome($("#x6")) //unwrap 1 element from end
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
div{border:solid 1px red;}
span{display:block}
</style>

<div>
    <span id="x1">1</span>
    <span id="x2">2</span>
    <span id="x3">3</span>
    <span id="x4">4</span>
    <span id="x5">5</span>
    <span id="x6">6</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can unwrap the spans from the common div wrapper and then just wrap x1 and x3 in their own new divs.

```js
$('span').unwrap();
$('#x1,#x3').wrap('<div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span id="x1">x1</span>
    <span id="x2">x2</span>
    <span id="x3">x3</span>
</div>
```

If your spans don't have IDs, you could do something like

```
$('div > span:even').wrap('<div>').parent().unwrap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two of javascript ways:

**First one:**

Wrap a given element in a new container element using plain JavaScript:

```js
 // element that will be wrapped
var el = document.querySelector('#x1');

// create wrapper container
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');

// insert wrapper before el in the DOM tree
el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);

// move el into wrapper
wrapper.appendChild(el);


var el2 = document.querySelector('#x3');
var wrapper2 = document.createElement('div');
el2.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper2, el2);
wrapper2.appendChild(el2);
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="x1">x1</span>
    <span id="x2">x2</span>
    <span id="x3">x3</span>
</div>
```

**Second one:**
Using `getElementById`

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.wrap = function(wrapper){
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, this);
  wrapper.appendChild(this);
}

  
  var element = document.getElementById('x1'); 
  element.wrap(document.createElement('div'));
  
   var elementx3 = document.getElementById('x3');
      elementx3.wrap(document.createElement('div'));
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="x1">x1</span>
    <span id="x2">x2</span>
    <span id="x3">x3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//some DOM1 vanilla... 
var parent = x1.parentElement;
//var cntnt =  parent.children;

//unwrapping the container div with ancient dhtml method
parent.outerHTML = parent.innerHTML;

// wrapping selected elements with jQuery
$("#x1,#x3").wrap('<div>');

// show the end-result HTML
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span id="x1"></span>
    <span id="x2"></span>
    <span id="x3"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.wrap()` and `.unwrap()` have never worked too well for me. Instead, I usually just wrap the elements `outerHTML` to wrap and use the `innerHTML` to unwrap. You mention a list in your comment, that's why I have a select here. Regardless how you select the spans, I think my button handler demonstrates what you are trying to achieve. This also doesn't require unique ids for each span nor does it matter how many you have.

```
PopulateSelect();

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('select option:selected').each(function(offset, span) {
    let $span = $(`span.unwrapped:eq(${span.index - offset})`);
    $span.removeClass('unwrapped')[0].outerHTML = `<div>${$span.html()}</div>`;
  });
  PopulateSelect();
});

function PopulateSelect() {
  let options = '';
  $('span.unwrapped').each(function() {
    options += `<option>${this.textContent}</option>`;
  });
  $('select').html(options);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8429pcpu/2/

This is a bit involved, so rather than spamming a bunch of links, feel free to ask about anything you don't understand.